# Sharpening Base Edge on Skis

Tags: skiing, ski-repair

I recently got a pair of downhill skis from a friend. The skis were only used a few times, so the base was in pretty good shape. The only issue was the edges were fairly rusty. I used a Swix pocket edger to remove all of the rust, on both the base and side edges. After some further reading on the internet, it seems that base sharpening is best left to professionals/ski shops. Was sharpening the base a mistake, and if so, will it cause issues down the road?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of people are doing the ski service themselves, there is no witchery about this. However, there is some things that can be done wrong as a beginner.
Manufacturers grind edges in a certain angle, depending on the ski. If you do the edges you should make sure that you do not change this angle accidentally as this will change how skis behave. There can also be the issue that your sharpening is not as regular as done by a maschine.

If you messed up anything, it can be fixed by regrinding the edges properly. This will cost you some material and in the long run may reduce the lifetime of the ski a bit. However, often a ski might simply fall out of favor and be replaced by a more modern model before wear on the edges becomes a real issue, so I would not care too much about this